# CTR mode Decryption

Tags: python, encryption, block

Someone help me please. This is the CTR mode decryption, it supposed to print letters but it does not. This is the decryption formula. the input are hexadecimal values and the output should be characters/letters

```
def ctr_dec(ys):

  xs = [] 

  ss = ["10101000", "10101001", "10101010", "10101011", "10101100", "10101101"]

  key = int("0X08", 16)

  for i in range(len(ys)):

    #163*(block-key+256)%256

    ei = chr(((163 * int(ss[i], 2) - key + 256) % 256) ^ int(ys[i], 16))

    #yi = hex(xs[i] ^ ei)

    xs.append(ei)

  return xs



def main():
  
cipher_ctr = ['0X8a', '0X21', '0Xba', '0X24']
  
ps_ctr = ctr_dec(cipher_ctr)
  
print("\nCBC decryption ", ps_ctr)
main()
```